# Generate a Table of contents every time a var changes

Tags: php, html, dynamic, html-table, tableofcontents

I tried to find any solution or question and I didn't find anything.

I'm working on a medical directory, is  a table with 3 columns and 3 td's in every row when the html is done I need to convert it to a PDF version.
So far everything is fine.

But later, I was asked for a change.
To insert an index of contents every time the city changed.

But the structure must be the same in all cases, 3 cols with 3 tds for row
This is the structure of my table:

```
$totals=count($bloque[$i]);

  for($i=0;$i<$totales;$i++){

     if($i%3 == 0) {$impression[]="<tr valign='top' >".$bloque3[$i];}
     if($i%3 == 1) {$impression[]=$bloque3[$i];}
     if($i%3 == 2) {$impression[]=$bloque[$i]."</tr>";}
}
```

---

After that I'm doing the comparison if the city is different then *structure of the index*.

```
if($thecity != $rows['city']){

    $index='<tr><th><span class="index" style="font-size:11px;"><small><b>'.$rows2['city '].'<br><br>Index of contents</b></small></span></th></tr>';
}
else{$index='';}
```

---

Next var is the structure of every td.

```
$bloque3[]='<span>'.$index.'</span><td width="30%"><p>'.$rows2['provider'].'</p>'.'<p>'.$rows2['service'].'</span>'.'<span>'.$rows2['benefits'].'<br />'.$rows2['city'].'</span></td>';
```

.

Every index must be in a new row,  but I'm including the index in  the same array  `bloque` because otherwise is not working.

The problem is every time `$index` exist, is inserting a row inside a row, which is not too bad in the browser, because browsers are intelligent - most of them ;)-
 But in pdf version  the tds looks awful, one above another, and index above another td.

Comment: Just use this http://pdfcrowd.com/

Comment: Is a dynamic table. But tks